# iOS UIImageView beneath UITableView doesn't display correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview, uistoryboard

I'm building a UITableView via the StoryBoard in XCode 6.3.1 for iPhone 6 app.

On this TableView, I want all of my cells, then beneath that, a UIImageView. I tested it for a small placeholder image, and it worked great. All of my cells display properly, and the image shows up beneath them.

The problem comes when I use my actual image (it's the size of the full screen). I want it to go directly below the Tableview, and have the bottom be viewable when the user scrolls down.
I tried messing with the view's attributes, and everything kept giving me some sort of issue. The default view mode of "Scale to Fill" makes the image look extremely distorted. Changing it to Aspect Fill makes the Image look perfect, but it makes all of the cells disappear when I run it (though not in the Storyboard for some reason)

Is there any way I can get the cells to display correctly, then place the undistorted image beneath it?

Comment: the imageview is inside the cell ? you can try `cell.contentView.clipsToBound = YES;` to see if it works correctly.

Comment: it's actually under the cell (as in down, not behind)

Comment: how about you set the imageView's clipsToBound property to YES?
`imageView.clipsToBound = YES;`